# Инициализация объектов в классе циклом

Tags: python, ооп, циклы

Почему в данном примере не рисуются виджеты ? Если создавать их без цикла, все работает без проблем .

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Just Testing...')
        new_labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4']
        self.widget_array = [QLabel() for _ in new_labels]
        y = 100
        for i in range(len(new_labels)):
            self.widget_array[i].setText(new_labels[i])
            self.widget_array[i].setGeometry(0, y, 100, 30)
            self.widget_array[i].setStyleSheet('color: black')
            self.widget_array[i].setFont(QFont('Arial', 18))
            y += 30

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ну в данном примере если нужно создать определенное количество виджетов (n) типа label и задать им одинаковые параметры

Comment: как вариант использовать self.widgets_array = [QLabel("Label%d"%i, self) for i in range(1,n+1)] далее for widget in widgets_array: widget.setProperty etc., сам не тестил но концепт думаю понятен.

Comment: Обновил первый пост . Сделал во вашему совету, но что-то идет не так...